# word2vec with different grammar

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding

what is the effect of word2vec if implemented on different language and different grammar? I mean word2vec is implemented on english corpus for the first time, is there any affect if we used another language corpus?

Answer (score 1):

Word2vec has been applied to many languages – and also as one part of language-to-language translation strategies, where word2vec models are learned on each language separately.

Word2vec is not dependent on any specifics of English grammar. Rather, it simply requires as input sequences of words in their natural ordering.

(Languages where words aren't clearly indicated with intervening whitespace/punctuation may require more complicated tokenization before their word-sequences are passed to word2vec training, but that's outside the word2vec algorithm itself, and once given proper word-tokens word2vec should still be able to learn word-vectors that have the usual desirable arrangments.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare word embeddings from models that have been trained on different corpora. You'll get nonsensical results because model A has no knowledge of the contexts that the words from model B has been seen in.

It is possible though to convert the word embeddings from model A into a new vector that exists in the vector space of model B. This is akin to translation, and the new word vector should be close to words in the other model's corpus that are similar in meaning to your original word (assuming that both models have been trained on data covering a similar range of contexts).

I've written a small package: [transvec](https://pypi.org/project/transvec/), which will do this for you in Python. It allows you to take words vectors from a pre-trained model for one language and translate them into word vectors in a completely different language. Here's an example where words are converted between English and Russian, using pre-trained Word2Vec models:

```
import gensim.downloader
from transvec.transformers import TranslationWordVectorizer

# Pretrained models in two different languages.
ru_model = gensim.downloader.load("word2vec-ruscorpora-300")
en_model = gensim.downloader.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300")

# Training data: pairs of English words with their Russian translations.
# The more you can provide, the better.
train = [
    ("king", "царь_NOUN"), ("tsar", "царь_NOUN"),
    ("man", "мужчина_NOUN"), ("woman", "женщина_NOUN")
]

bilingual_model = TranslationWordVectorizer(en_model, ru_model).fit(train)

# Find words with similar meanings across both languages.
bilingual_model.similar_by_word("царица_NOUN", 1) # "queen"
# [('king', 0.7763221263885498)]
```